# "have arrived" or "arrived"

Tags: tense

1. His father won't be able to leave for Delhi until they **have arrived**.
2. His father won't be able to leave for Delhi until they **arrive**.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Another, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87962/use-of-present-perfect-with-until-until-hes-eaten-everything/87964#87964

Answer (score 2):

Both sound natural. They technically mean something slightly different:

The first sentence would mean that he can't leave until *after* they arrive.

The second sentence means that he can leave the moment they arrive.

But in practice, both are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do they sound natural, bur they are both  correct, grammatically. Since you put the question, are you sure now that they are interchangable in the context?

Comment: I thought we can use only "present perfect" in until-clause.